# hidden inputs with same name: how to send only the values of selected checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, checkbox

We have a number of checkboxes linked to several hidden fields with the SAME NAME. How could we send only the values of the selected checkboxes?

php

```
<input type"checkbox" name="<?echo $filename;?>_<?echo $variable;?>"
id="filename_<?echo $variable;?>" value="1">

<input type="hidden" name="item_<?echo $filename;?>" 
value="<?echo $quantity;?>">
```

If two or more checkboxes with the same name are selected, how can we then obtain the correct value for each hidden input rather than always the value of the last one?

our generated html

```
<input type"checkbox" name="idfilename_1"
<input type="hidden" name="item_idfilename" value="7">

<input type"checkbox" name="idfilename_2"
<input type="hidden" name="item_idfilename" value="5">

<input type"checkbox" name="idfilename_3"
<input type="hidden" name="item_idfilename" value="11">
```

Comment: Use also `item_idfilename1` `item_idfilename2` ...

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="item_idfilename[]" value="7">
<input type="checkbox" name="item_idfilename[]" value="5">
<input type="checkbox" name="item_idfilename[]" value="11">
```

This way you'll get a list of checked checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use array for both checkboxes and hiddens.
Having checkboxes called check[1],check[2],check[3] and hiddens called item_hidden[1],item_hidden[2],etc.. you could relate every checkbox with a hidden input.

So your output will be:

```
<input type"checkbox" name="idfilename[1]" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="item_idfilename[1]" value="7">

<input type"checkbox" name="idfilename[2]" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="item_idfilename[2]" value="5">

<input type"checkbox" name="idfilename[3]" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="item_idfilename[3]" value="11">
```

Server-side, you will cycle idfilename and, if value is set (So checkbox has been checked), you'll take value from item_idfilename array.

Comment: I have to do this: Your answer shows input fields with `1` in it, and i dont think that is that what the OP wants on the real web-page, check the syntax ;-)

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions What does it have to do with anything question-related?

Comment: That your code wont work if used unchanged, because of the missing `=`. I dont want to be rude too  :-)

Comment: I thing @nvisser has the best solution here (only one input solution). Have a nice day.

Comment: I just can't see the error.. There's no missing equal sign.. value=1 for checkboxes is just for server-side check. He doesn't have to use that value, but hidden fields one.. OP asked for a solution which allows him to have both a checkbox and a hidden field, so @nvisser solution could possibly be unavailable for him.

Comment: `type"checkbox"` <-- missing `=`

Comment: And you are right that no answer here keep this in mind: `<?echo $filename;?>_<?echo $variable;?>` from the OP question

Comment: Thanks for noticing, but it's irrelevant as this is generated by the OP.

Comment: Thanks but we cannot really use the array method as we then need to use one variable in a second page rather than the whole array. We cannot GET one element via its position within the array as such a position is determined by the individual choice of the end user via a checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Normaly its done this way

```
<input type"checkbox" name="idfilename_1">
<input type="hidden" name="item_idfilename_1" value="7">
```

Only the checked once will have an field/index in the POST array.

On PHP side get the fields from the selected checkboxes.

If know for example an array_key exists e.g. `idfilename_1` then you can take the value from `$_POST['item_idfilename_1']`, if not leave it.

Keep in mind: Only selected checkboxes will have an field in the POST array!

Comment: It's always a bad decision to have "numbered" variables when you can use arrays and provide more flexibility.

Comment: @Michael Di Prisco I now, but in my example you cant use `idfilename[]` because you dont get the relation any more on server side to the `item_idfilename_` fields.

Comment: You can by putting key between brackets. In OP's cycle, we have a variable called $variable which is unique and incremental, so we can use such variable as array key.

Comment: @Michael Di Prisco It was just an example and instant answer, i would do it in a other way. So i have made it simple here. I dont really know why he is using 2 inputs for that .....

Comment: @Michael Di Prisco    And `bad decision` is not always a `wrong answer` in php/html world ;-)

Comment: Of course, didn't want to accuse you of giving wrong answers in any way, but if we can offer a better way of doing things, I'd prefer to do that :) Sorry if I seemed rude.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
  var $checkedInput = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked');
  if($checkedInput){
        var hiddenValue= $checkedInput.next('input[type=hidden]').val();
  }
```

--------------- or-------------------

```
 var $checkedInput= $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').next('input[type=hidden]')
                   .map(function() {
                         return $(this).val();
                   }).get();
```

you will get an array like `["7", "5", "11"]` as per your code.

Comment: Bad decision. Always prevent using jQuery when possible and relay on browser-consistent and performing methods, such as cross-browser input array naming.

Comment: Your solution seems very promising but the script appears not to work. Are we missing something? :-) Any tweaks?

Answer (score 0):

I used `next()` to get the next node value

```js
$('[type~=checkbox]').change(function(){
  alert($(this).next().val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="idfilename_1">
<input type="hidden" name="item_idfilename" value="7">

<input type="checkbox" name="idfilename_2">
<input type="hidden" name="item_idfilename" value="5">

<input type="checkbox" name="idfilename_3">
<input type="hidden" name="item_idfilename" value="11">
```